# How to initialize a GTKDialog in Python (Gtk3+)

Tags: python, gtk3

When creating a GTK Dialog in python the "old" way:

```
class URLDialog(Gtk.Dialog):
def __init__(self, parent):
    Gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, _t("URL_DLG"), parent, 0,
        (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
         Gtk.STOCK_OK, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))
```

I get the following warning:

> PyGTKDeprecationWarning: The "buttons" argument must be a Gtk.ButtonsType enum value. Please use the "add_buttons" method for adding buttons. See: https://wiki.gnome.org/PyGObject/InitializerDeprecations

The link is not very explicit, and trying to get the buttons out of the initalizer leads to other, more severe problems.

My question is: What is the proper,offical and correct way to initialize such a dialog?

Comment: Which version of Gtk?

Comment: GTK 3.24 with python 3.7

Answer (score 2):

I can't reconstruct your problem, but I would assume this should fix it:

```
Gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, _t("URL_DLG"), parent, 0)
self.add_buttons(Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
                 Gtk.STOCK_OK, Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
```

**EDIT:** as pointed out by OP

```
Gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, title = _t("URL_DLG"), 
                          parent = parent, 
                          flags = 0)
self.add_buttons(Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
                 Gtk.STOCK_OK, Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
```

Comment: Yes it does. thank you. But deprecation goes further:
Gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, title=_t("URL_DLG"), parent=parent, flags=0)
They don't want these "freefloating" arguments anymore.... But now is silence ;-)

Comment: Since this question came up, I use the `-Wd` flag in Python, and I discovered a bunch of deprecations myself.